# Como mostrar una imagen de un Map de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, imagen, map

Muchas gracias por tomarse la molestia de leer mi consulta, estoy teniendo problemas para mostrar una imagen en una card, me imprime toda la informacion pero la imagen no lo hace, ya probe de mil maneras

```
fetch("js/api.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(user => {
      const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      console.log(user)
    })
    users = data.map(user => {
      const card = userCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true).children[0]
      const header = card.querySelector("h5")
      const imgage = card.querySelector("img")
      const body = card.querySelector("p")

      imgage.setAttribute = `<img src="${user.image}"/>`
      header.textContent = user.modelo
      body.textContent = user.precio
      userCardContainer.append(card)
      return { modelo: user.modelo, precio: user.precio, img: user.img, element: card }
      
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la línea

```
imgage.setAttribute = `<img src="${user.image}"/>`
```

por

```
imgage.setAttribute('img', user.image)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Soy nuevo con JS y eso me estaba frustrando porque sabia que era algo muy tonto que se me estaba pasando

Comment: Animo, todos hemos comenzado desde cero